# In hydrostatics, is it possible for the bouancy to be greater than the weight of a body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, buoyancy, fluid-statics

In the diagram we have two bodies, with density and volume $\delta$ and $V$, and a fluid $\ell$.

$$\delta_1=0,7 \rm\frac{gr}{cm^3}$$
$$\delta_2=2 \rm\frac{gr}{cm^3}$$
$$V_1=100 \rm {cm^3}$$
$$V_2=10 \rm {cm^3}$$
$$\delta_\ell = 1,2 \rm\frac{gr}{cm^3}$$

The system is static.

[image]

I need to find $(1)$ The tension of the rope $(2)$ the buoyancy $1$ receives due to the liquid.

I solved it, but I'm getting strange results:

Let $W$ be the weighs, $B$ be the buoyancy and $T$ the tension. Then, since the system is static:

$$B_1+B_2-W_1-W_2=0$$

(the tensions cancel out)

But $W_1= \delta_1 \cdot g \cdot V_1$, $W_2= \delta_2 \cdot g \cdot V_2$ and $B_2 = \delta_\ell \cdot g \cdot V_2$ (since the body is fully submerged):

$$\eqalign{
  10\frac{{\text{m}}}{{{{\text{s}}^{\text{2}}}}}\left( {70{\text{gr}} + 20{\text{gr}} - 12{\text{gr}}} \right) = B_1 \cr 
  10\frac{\rm m}{{{\rm s^2}}}\left( {0,078\rm{kg} } \right) = B{_1} \cr 
  0,78{\text{N}} = B{_1} \cr} $$

It seems strange that the buoyancy is greater than the weigh of the body ($0,7 \rm N$), is that possible?
Also, I can't figure out how to obtain the tension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that buoyancy is just a force. There's no reason it necessarily has to bear any particular relationship to weight.

Try drawing a free-body diagram for each of the two objects individually, and writing the corresponding force equation, and you should see what's going on.

Comment: But is it legitimate to "separate" the system? If the rope is cut, $1$ will probably float upwards, and $2$ will sink, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, it is. When you have a system that consists of multiple individual objects, you can always draw a free body diagram (and write the force equation) for any of the objects individually, or for the system as a whole, or indeed for any possible grouping of the objects. All these equations are going to be satisfied. Drawing a diagram for part of the system doesn't mean cutting the rope.

Comment: I didn't mean I couldn't draw the FBD. I think I get what you mean - I can consider $T_2+B_2-W_2=0$ for body $1$. Ideal conditions will ensure $T_1=-T_2$.

Comment: Yeah... though how does the weight of object 2 $W_2$ act on body 1? ;-)

Comment: I don't follow that last hint =/. I've determined $T=0,08N$, though.

Comment: I mean, you wrote an equation involving all forces that act on body 2, but you said it was the force equation for body 1. Do you see what doesn't make sense about that? (Was it a typo?)

Comment: Oh, sure it was!